# How was Vajrajwala, Wife of gigantic Kumbhakaran in comparison to him? How did they live together?

Tags: ramayana, kumbhakarna

Maharshi Valmiki in First Sarga, Uttarkand, Ramayan says that there was nothing as big as Kumbhakaran, and that he had two sons Kumbh and Nikumbh.

> [image]
> [image]

Do we have any details about marriage of Kumbhakaran and his wife Vajrajwala in scriptures? Was she also as big as him? If not, how did they live together? How were their children born?

Comment: The wife’s name is Vajravala, daughter of Virochana. Other information about her is not available in Valmiki

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why were Ravana and Bali (the Asura not Vanara) enemies when Bali's daughter was married to Ravan's brother Kumbhakarna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23818/why-were-ravana-and-bali-the-asura-not-vanara-enemies-when-balis-daughter-was)

Comment: @Archit She was Virochana's granddaughter/Dohitri (daughter's daughter)..

Comment: @YDS okay hadn’t checked actual shloka. As per actual shloka In your answer, she should be grand daughter of Bali (Vairochana, not Virochana)

Comment: @YDS thanks, i was able to find info on her genealogy. I was looking for info in comparison to greatness of Kumbhakaran and how they lived.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only refrence of Kumbhakarna's wife I found is in [Uttarkanda;](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424773.html)

> “There, with their consent, he chose two wives for his two brothers; the daughter of Virocana, **named Vajravala, was given by him to Kumbhakama,** and Bibishana received as wife the virtuous Sarama, the daughter of the King of the Gandharvas, the magnanimous Shailusha, and she had been born on the shores of the Lake Manasa.

In [Shiva Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226521.html), Kumbhakarna had sex with one more women called Karkati, and they had a child *Bhima.*

> ## Karkaṭī said:—

> 10. **Your father was Kumbhakarṇa the younger brother of Rāvaṇa.** That powerful demon was killed by Rāma along with his brother.

> 11. Once that powerful demon Kumbhakarṇa had been here. He caught me forcefully and enjoyed me.

> 12. That powerful demon left me here itself and returned to Laṅkā. That Laṅkā was not visited by me. I have been staying here alone.